# Adding a factor to 2 values

Tags: c#

A method calculates the percentage of 2 given in points (for example 15/20 and 16/20) and returns the total %.

But the problem is when i try to add weight to those values.
Meaning standard weight factor 1 and weight factor 2 for both values are set on 1 (normal % calculation).

But how exactly do i add weights to them? 
Assuming i want to add a weight factor of 2 to the first value and leave the second one to standard(1). (So a certain score is more important then a other, hence the % changes.)

**Calculation with integers**
input 15 and 16  (score on /20)
With default weight factors (1 & 1) the overal percentage would be 77

If the weight factors are changed to 2 (for 15) and standard 1 (for 16) the total % would be 76.

What would be the best way to implement this, cannot find anything about this.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,

> ((15/20)+(16/20)) / 2 = 0.775 (77.5%)

instead of 77% (you shouldn't round until you perform a final calculation, e.g. for a grading system, different assignment types would have different weights and systems should never round until they display a final percentage.)

To weight one amount as 2 instead of 1, you would take the amount into account twice:

> ((15/20)+(15/20)+(16/20)) / 3 = 0.766
>   (76.6%)

(I know this because I have great knowledge of Pearson's [PowerSchool](http://www.pearsonschoolsystems.com/products/powerschool/))